# HOw to return a null in an object class

Tags: java

I am trying to get an object (Space) and check if it overlaps an obstacle. if it does, i want to return a null, if not then return the space object. But i dont know how to do that. do i put a if statment at the end of the program outside of the for loop?

```
public Object checkob(Obstacle obstacle, Space space, int numofobst) {
  int object = space.getX();

  System.out.println("space location is " + object + " and the space is " + space.getName());
  for (int ob = 0; ob < numofobst; ob++) {
    if (object == obstacle.getX()) {
      System.out.println("Space " + space.getName() + " is not able to be choosen");
      return null;
    }
    System.out.println("Space " + space.getName() + " is able to be choosen");
    return space;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add `return null;` before you end the method `checkob`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to move `return space` outside of your loop

```
public Object checkob(Obstacle obstacle,Space space,int numofobst){
    int object = space.getX();

    System.out.println("space location is " + object +" and the space is " + space.getName());
    for (int ob = 0; ob < numofobst; ob++){
        if (object == obstacle.getX()){
            System.out.println("Space " +space.getName() + " is not able to be choosen");
            return null;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Space " +space.getName() + " is able to be choosen");
    return space;
}
```

Comment: ok i think i got it. i just added a counter to the for loop. if it was not possible then not possible = 1. at the end outside of the for loop, i check to see if notpossible >0. if it was return null. if not return the class. Good?